# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith' when Configuring interfaces using with_items (ansible)

Tags: python, ansible

I would like to use with_items to configure my interfaces in my switch but I have this error when I run my playbook.

Can someone help me please ?

Here is the output with -vvvv options:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
failed: [DTY] (item={u'int_name': u'GigabitEthernet1/0/46', u'vlan_id': 400, u'desc': u'Internet vers Routeur'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "desc": "Internet vers Routeur",
        "int_name": "GigabitEthernet1/0/1",
        "vlan_id": 400
    },
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-26021FmRvka/ansible-tmp-1637232459.72-26034-173735680808565/AnsiballZ_ios_config.py\", line 102, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-26021FmRvka/ansible-tmp-1637232459.72-26034-173735680808565/AnsiballZ_ios_config.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-26021FmRvka/ansible-tmp-1637232459.72-26034-173735680808565/AnsiballZ_ios_config.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.network.ios.ios_config', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 188, in run_module\n    fname, loader, pkg_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 82, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 72, in _run_code\n    exec code in run_globals\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ios_config_payload_4u0HB1/ansible_ios_config_payload.zip/ansible/modules/network/ios/ios_config.py\", line 569, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ios_config_payload_4u0HB1/ansible_ios_config_payload.zip/ansible/modules/network/ios/ios_config.py\", line 472, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ios_config_payload_4u0HB1/ansible_ios_config_payload.zip/ansible/modules/network/ios/ios_config.py\", line 375, in get_candidate_config\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ios_config_payload_4u0HB1/ansible_ios_config_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/network/common/config.py\", line 422, in add\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ios_config_payload_4u0HB1/ansible_ios_config_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/network/common/config.py\", line 113, in ignore_line\nAttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
```

here is my playbook:

```
- name: "CONFIGURE INTERFACE IN ACCESS MODE"
      ios_config:
        commands:
          - description {{ item.desc }}
          - switchport mode access
          - switchport access vlan {{ item.vlan_id }}
        parents: interface {{ item.int_name}}
      with_items: 
        - {int_name: 'GigabitEthernet 1/0/1', desc: 'Internet vers Routeur OBS', vlan_id: 400 }
        - {int_name: 'GigabitEthernet 1/0/2', desc: 'Internet OBS vers FW-907411-F', vlan_id: 400 }
        - {int_name: 'GigabitEthernet 1/0/3', desc: 'Internet BBOX vers FW-907411-F', vlan_id: 401 }
        - {int_name: 'GigabitEthernet 1/0/9', desc: 'MGMT vers FW-907411-F', vlan_id: 20 }
        - {int_name: 'GigabitEthernet 1/0/10', desc: 'SONOS', vlan_id: 20 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a little thing. It should had an escape character before the { and the int_name. I have finally solved the problem. I hope it will be very interisting for those who begin with network automation using Ansible.

```
- name: "CONFIGURE INTERFACE IN ACCESS MODE"
      ios_config:
        commands:
          - description {{ item.desc }}
          - switchport mode access
          - switchport access vlan {{ item.vlan_id }}
        parents: interface {{ item.int_name}}
      with_items: 
        - { int_name: 'GigabitEthernet 1/0/1', desc: 'Internet vers Routeur OBS', vlan_id: 400 }
        - { int_name: 'GigabitEthernet 1/0/2', desc: 'Internet OBS vers FW-907411-F', vlan_id: 400 }
        - { int_name: 'GigabitEthernet 1/0/3', desc: 'Internet BBOX vers FW-907411-F', vlan_id: 401 }
        - { int_name: 'GigabitEthernet 1/0/9', desc: 'MGMT vers FW-907411-F', vlan_id: 20 }
        - { int_name: 'GigabitEthernet 1/0/10', desc: 'SONOS', vlan_id: 20 }
```